# Problem with nested \noexpand and \edef

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a LaTeX problem and want to explain it with the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \def\myline{A}
  \edef\myline{\myline \noexpand\bf B}
  \edef\myline{\myline C}

  \myline
\end{document}
```

I have to build up a line incrementally. This happens inside of a for loop.
The problem is that I want to highlight some text in bold, but whenever I expand my line, I get the following error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.9 \myline

? X
```

I think, it is because of the third `\edef`, which tries to expand the `\bf` in the second `\edef`, however I have to expand it to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: BTW: `\bf` is deprecated. Use either `\bfseries` or `\textbf{<text>}` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see what happens

```
\def\myline{A}
\edef\myline{\myline \noexpand\bf B}
```

Given the first line, the second is equivalent to

```
\def\myline{A\bf B}
```

Now, when you say

```
\edef\myline{\myline C}
```

TeX expands the inner `\myline` completely and this is what it becomes
(result of `\show\myline` edited to avoid bad line breaks):

```
> \myline=macro:
->A\protect \protect \protect \edef OT1{OT1}\let \enc@update \relax
 \protect \edef cmr{cmr}\protect \edef m{m}\protect \edef n{n}
 \protect \xdef \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 }\OT1/cmr/m/n/10
 \size@update \enc@update \ignorespaces \relax \protect \relax 
 \protect \edef m{bx}\protect \xdef \OT1/cmr/m/n/10  
 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10}\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \size@update \enc@update BC.
```

which is surely not what TeX likes to see when executing the newly defined `\myline`.

The problem is that `\noexpand` inhibits expansion *once*: in the second `\edef`, the token `\bf` *will* be expanded. This is a "correct" way to proceed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\myline{A}
\protected@edef\myline{\myline \bfseries B}
\protected@edef\myline{\myline C}

\myline
\end{document}
```

Note that `\protect` in front of `\bfseries` is not needed, as `\bfseries` is already a "LaTeX robust command".

Another way is to use `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries

\begin{document}

\def\myline{A}
\edef\myline{\myline \bfseries B}
\edef\myline{\myline C}

\myline
\end{document}
```

This will make `\bfseries` "protected forever" inside an `\edef`.

Martin suggests in his answer to use `\appto`, which is quite a good way to build a macro by accretion:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\myline{}
\appto\myline{A \bfseries B}
\appto\myline{C}
```

In this case we get the same result as

```
\def\myline{A \bfseries BC}
```

If the accretion has to be global, you can use `\gappto` (which is equivalent to the kernel macro `\g@addto@macro`).

Another strategy is to use token registers:

```
\newtoks\mylinetoks

\mylinetoks={}
\mylinetoks={A \bfseries B}
\mylinetoks=\expandafter{\mylinetoks C}
```

Of course the register can be used as many times as one likes, it's necessary to allocate it only once. The kernel provides `\addto@hook`:

```
\newtoks\mylinetoks

\makeatletter
\mylinetoks={}
\addto@hook\mylinetoks{A \bfseries B}
\addto@hook\mylinetoks{\mylinetoks C}
```

For using the contents of the register, you say

```
\the\mylinetoks
```

Answer (score 7):

As you said yourself `\bf` will be expanded by the second `\edef`. You need to add a `\noexpand` for this `\edef` as well, which has to be prefixed itself by a `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \def\myline{A}
  \edef\myline{\myline \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\bf B}
  \edef\myline{\myline C}

  \myline
\end{document}
```

This of course gets out of hands fast if you have more `\edef`, especially if you don't now the exact number.

Better would be to use `\protect` and `\protected@edef` which makes sure that the `\protect` will stay independent of the number of expansions. In the normal text it then doesn't do anything, so it doesn't cause any trouble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \def\myline{A}
  \makeatletter
  \protected@edef\myline{\myline \protect\bf B}
  \protected@edef\myline{\myline C}
  \makeatother

  \myline
\end{document}
```

If you want to simple append material to `\myline` without expanding anything yet, you can use `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\myline\expandafter{\myline <new stuff>}
```

So the old definition is expanded before it is defined again.

There is also a LaTeX macro `\g@addto@macro\yourmacro{<stuff>}` which adds stuff to the given macro, but however globally. It uses a token register (*toks*) for this.

The `etoolbox` package has some nice macros for this, like `\appto\yourmacro{<stuff>}` which works only locally.

Comment: You might also want to explain how to use a toks to achieve the same thing without the awkward `\expandafter` approach.

Comment: @JosephWright: I added the macro which use toks now. Not sure if you should explain exactly how they work.

Answer (score 4):

As egreg noted, both `\bf` and `\textbf` are *LaTeX protected*. There is no need for `\protect` behind them in `\protected@edef`.

Maybe this is what Joseph Wright refers to:

```
\def\myline{A}
% \bfseries needs localization:
\@temptokena{{\bfseries B}}
\edef\myline{\myline \the\@temptokena}
```

The problem was that `\protect` became `\relax` when you made the definition. You could have done

```
% In document preamble:
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\protedef{\let\protedef\protected@edef}
\makeatother
% Subsequently:
\def\myline{A}
\protedef\myline{\myline {\bfseries B}}
```

Rather than load a package to robustify `\bf` or `\bfseries`, you can simply do

```
\newcommand*\mybf{} % \mybf is definable.
\let\mybf\bfseries
\protected\def\bfseries{\mybf}
\def\myline{A}
\edef\myline{\myline {\bfseries B}}
```

But this changes `\bfseries` globally, which (like \robustify) should only be done locally or within the document body.

In case you wonder how this doesn't lead to a cyclic definition, here is how it works in document body:

```
{\bfseries XX}

\bfseries->\mybf
\mybf->\protect\bfseries
{\relax}
\bfseries->\not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf\fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
```