# Error with expansions

Tags: tex-core, expansion

I am getting an error while trying to compile this minimal example:

min.cls:

```
\ProvidesClass{min}

\LoadClass{minimal}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\newenvironment{myenv}{}{
\def\aaa{test }
\expandafter\def\csname bbb\endcsname{$4\sqrt{2}$}
\bbb
\edef\aaa{\aaa \bbb}
\aaa
}

\endinput
```

mintest.tex:

```
\documentclass{min}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
Test
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Running latex over mintest.tex produces this error:

```
ERROR: Use of \@sqrt doesn't match its definition.

--- TeX said ---
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.7 \end{myenv}
```

Peculiar. I want to expand the definition of `\aaa` by concatenation. Any thoughts?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't like that commands with optional arguments are passed through an `\edef`. It's difficult to say more from your example, but `\protected@edef\aaa{\aaa\bbb}` should work.

Comment: @egreg WOW, thanks, it worked. Can you post as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX doesn't like to find commands with optional arguments or defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` inside an `\edef`; `\sqrt` fall in the first type, `\bfseries` in the second one.

In your case

```
\protected@edef\aaa{\aaa\bbb}
```

will work.

Be careful, though: fragile commands such as `\linebreak` *can't* go in `\protected@edef` directly and must be preceded by `\protect`. Some knowledge of how dubious commands are defined is necessary.

See also [Minimal \protected@edef example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example) and [Problem with nested \noexpand and \edef](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39195/problem-with-nested-noexpand-and-edef)